# Is this a glitch or a problem with my computer?

Tags: pc, xcom-enemy-unknown

I installed XCom a while ago and something horrible happened. When I changed my point of view by pressing the Q button, and then I move one of my soldiers, my screen froze and I had to force-shut-it-down in order to allow it to recover. I have been using this same computer for the past year and this never happened before.

Comment: Unfortunately, XCom is one of the buggiest games I've seen. Ranging from zombies that look like they're alive (but aren't) after you load a save where they were supposed to be dead, all the way to not being able to issue any commands (leaving me no other choice but to kill the process through the task manager, since Alt+F4 won't work either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with your graphics card. What graphic card does your computer have?

Try to install the most up to date graphic driver, that may solve the problem

Comment: thx for the tip im am gonna try it out